# How to Remove wpautop in woocommerce includes folder class-wc-order-item.php

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to remove wpautop from

```
display_value => wpautop( make_clickable( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', $display_value, $meta, $this ) ) )
```

in **plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order-item.php**

I don't know where to add remove_filters and add_action. Please tell the way to remove wpautop without editing in woocommerce core file

Comment: class-wc-order-item.php is not a template. It's a core WooCommerce file, and a very important one at that. Why do you want to edit this? Modifications to core plugin functionality can typically be done with filters, and there is likely a filter that will let you do what you want to do, you just need to specify it. Editing the core file is not something you can safely do, so the answer to the question as written is: you can't.

Comment: I need to customise this.So i want the way to overwrite it from my child theme.

Comment: I added more to my question, probably while you were writing. Can you check it again.

Comment: Actually i need to remove wpautop from `display_value' => wpautop( make_clickable( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', $display_value, $meta, $this ) ) ),` How to add filters and where can i add

Comment: Can you update your question with the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you @JacobPeattie. Updated the question with specific problem

Comment: The template in the question is different to the one in your original question. This new file is in the templates folder, so should be replaceable by placing a version inside `/woocommerce/emails` in your theme.